# how to compile flite tts and use in c# code?

Tags: c#, cygwin, flite

i need to know the steps to compile the flite tts using cygwin 
and then how can i generate DLL file to use it in c# code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> i need to know the steps to compile the flite tts

Did you read the [Windows Support section of the Installation docs](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/doc/flite_4.html#SEC5)?

> Flite has been successfully compiled
>   by a number of different groups under
>   Windows CE. The system should compile
>   under Embedded Visual Studio but we
>   not have the full details.
>
> The system as distributed does compile
>   under the gcc `mingw32ce` toolchain
>   available from
>   http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/. The
>   current version can be compiled and
>   run under WinCE with a primitive
>   application called `flowm`. `flowm` is
>   a simple application that allows
>   playing of typed-in text, or full text
>   to speech on a file. Files should be a
>   simple ascii text files `*.txt`. The
>   application allows the setting of the
>   byte position to start synthesis from.
>
> Assuming you have `mingw32ce`
>   installed you can configure as
>
> ```
> ./configure --target=arm-wince
> make
> ```
>
> The resulting binary is given in
>   `wince/flowm.exe`. If you copy this
>   onto your Windows Mobile device and
>   run it, it should allow you to speak
>   typed-in text and any `*.txt` files
>   you have on your device.